Как открыть результат формы в popup?
Всем доброго дня! Помогите решить проблему. Есть форма, в которой после заполнения полей и нажатия на кнопку должно произойти открытие popup окна с дальнейшими действиями. Но:

Не передаются POST данные формы. (этот вопрос решаем через JS, думаю разберусь);
Желаемый URL открывается в POPUP,но одновременно с ним же, он открывается и в основном окне.

В идеале, должна открываться следующая страница с формой в popup, а на текущей просто очищаться поля.


let params = `scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,
width=600,height=600,left=300,top=200`;

$('form').submit(function(e) {
  var empty = $(this).parent().find("input").filter(function() {
    return this.value === "";
  });
  if (!empty.length) {

    function openPopup() {
      window.open('adder.php', 'Оприходование', params);
    };

    $('form input').not(':button, :submit').val('');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
<form method="post" action="purchases.php">
       <input name="nameof" placeholder="Поставщик" list="first">
          <datalist id="first">
            <?php  foreach ($rows as $row) 
             { print ('<option value="'.$row['kontname'].'">');  
                  }
              ?>
            </datalist>
            <input name="type" placeholder="Тип товара" list="second">
             <datalist id="second">
            <?php  foreach ($tops as $top) {
           print ('<option value="'.$top['g_type'].'">');  
                  }
              ?>
          <input class="button" onclick="openPopup()" type="submit"> 
        </form>




datalist не закрыт тег. функция openPopup не доступна для onclick="openPopup()"

наверное при копировании и удалении лишнего кода убрал. У меня уже глаз замылен - какой тег не закрыт?

какой тег не закрыт - datalist

из примера стоит вообще убрать php код, он может влиять, только если разметка неверная генерируется. Но по приведенному шаблону этого нельзя узнать
